# Draper and RSpec and Factory Girl Controller Specs on Rails 4 App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4, factory-bot, draper

I am using Draper for the first time and it's working great...except for the fact that it broke most of my specs.  An example:

I am setting up an account_settings_controller_spec.rb

```
describe '#create' do
  before do
    @user = create :user
   end
end
```

This worked totally fine before (I have `config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods` set to call the factories like this)

However now when I call `create :user` I get `undefined method 'full_name' for class 'User'` which is a method I moved from my User model to my UserDecorator.

This is strange as the factory, nor the spec, use the `full_name` method.

I've tried multiple things:

- `ApplicationController.new.set_current_view_context` in the before block (which results in an error)
- `require 'draper/test/rspec_integration'` to my spec_helper.rb (which does nothing)
- adding `before/after(:create) { |instance| instance.decorate }` to my factory (which also does nothing)

I'm not sure what I am missing here, or even why the error is being thrown. Perhaps my decorators aren't being included when RSpec boots up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh ha!

I knew I was being stupid.

It's because I was using friendly_id

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :slug_candidates, use: :slugged

  ...

  def slug_candidates
    [:full_name, :id]
  end
end
```

I just moved the `full_name` method back to the model and it works.